# can we load test data thorugh csv using Test.loadData for custom objects?

Tags: unit-test

I am trying to load test data of custom object in my DB using Test.loadData method from csv file.The error I am getting states that "System.StringException: Unknown field: Type__c".

Comment: This error suggests that your CSV file has a column header that is unknown to the object you're trying to load. Make sure the column headers match the fields defined in the object. If the problem were loading into the custom object itself (because it didn't exist), you'd get a different error.

Comment: Yeah...I just got that too.In my org i have managed package.So what I was missing is...the package name need to be used as prefix for the field.